# msgraph client to communicate with OneDrive

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

How to properly use msgraph-sdk and does it even work as expected?

```
import asyncio
from azure.identity.aio import EnvironmentCredential
from kiota_authentication_azure.azure_identity_authentication_provider import AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider
from msgraph import GraphRequestAdapter
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

credential = EnvironmentCredential()
scopes = ['User.Read']

auth_provider = AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(credential, scopes=scopes) #type:ignore

request_adapter = GraphRequestAdapter(auth_provider)
client = GraphServiceClient(request_adapter)
user = asyncio.run(client.me.get())
print(user)
```

This simple code from example makes a request but with exception `Content: {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope User.Read is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI)`

If I change scopes to `/.default` than it throws an error

```
Content: {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope /.default is not valid
```

App is registered, client secret is valid for a year.

Comment: Can you try using the fully scope URI? `https://graph.microsoft.com/,default`

Comment: I tried it too. Best solution to use strict API endpoints with simple HTTP client, msgraph is still in development stage anyway

Comment: Check out this answer by @tiropp [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776730/cant-request-oauth2-token-for-specific-scope-with-azure-ad-and-client-credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776730/cant-request-oauth2-token-for-specific-scope-with-azure-ad-and-client-credential)